# Add multiple values to array in single JSON Patch operation?

Tags: arrays, json, rest, http, json-patch

I have a json object like this:

```
{
    "content" : [
        {
            "id" : 54
            "foo" : "bar"
        },
        {
            "id" : 43
            "foo" : "bar"
        },
        {
            "id" : 76
            "foo" : "bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I want to add multiple items to the content array (order doesn't matter) can I add to it with a json patch with a single line/ operation with something like this?

```
{ "op": "add", "path": "/content/-", "value": [
        {
            "id" : 34
            "foo" : "bar"
        },
        {
            "id" : 23
            "foo" : "bar"
        },
        {
            "id" : 87
            "foo" : "bar"
        }
    ] 
}
```

Or do I have to do an additional line for each object I want to add?

EDIT: To be clear I want to append, not replace the content.

Comment: I have the feeling you are not sure what you want to do.
why not:
```
{ "op":"add","path":{"content":[]}} or  { "op":"add","path":{"content": { "values": []}}}
```

Comment: Won't that delete the existing items stored there? To be clear I want to append not replace.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this seems not (yet?) possible... as the Json Patch specification states :

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4.1

> The "add" operation performs one of the following functions, depending upon what the target location references:
>
> - If the target location specifies an array index, a new value is
>   inserted into the array at the specified index.
> - If the target location specifies an object member that does not
>   already exist, a new member is added to the object.
> - **If the target location specifies an object member that does
>   exist, that member's value is replaced.**